# FFTW for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there is any way to use [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) library inside Windows Phone 8 ?

I tried to reference it directly of-course i cant, i wonder if there is any way to call native dll from Windows Phone 8.

Note: I will be calling it from C#.

Comment: Given the c# tag I take it you want to call it from C# and not C++?

Comment: yes, i want to call it from C#

Comment: Not sure if DFT, but I know this nuget package has FFT, and is wp8 compat:  http://nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/

Comment: i wish, but it doesn't get installed on WP8 for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a native DLL directly from C# without using a Windows Runtime component which wraps the native DLL and provides an interface that .NET can call.

You must also make sure that your library is correctly built for the phone (correct CPU architecture and libraries) before you can write a Windows Runtime wrapper for it.